# Hibernate one-to-one through intermediate table

Tags: hibernate, orm

Given these three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE USERS
(
    USER_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME_FIRST VARCHAR(15),
    NAME_LAST VARCHAR(20),
    LOGIN_NAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    PASSWORD VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    ...
);

CREATE TABLE PROJECTS
(
    PROJECT_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    PROJECT_NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    ...
);

CREATE TABLE LAST_PROJECTS
(
    USER_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    PROJECT_ID INT NOT NULL
);
```

And these two entities:

```
public class User
{
    private Long userID;
    ...
    private Project lastProject;
    ...
}

public class Project
{
    private Long projectID;
    private String projectName;
    ...
}
```

What happens is that for performance reasons, the Users table was split into two
tables: the permanent user details (or at least those that do not change much) 
and one for temporary user details; those who change on a daily basis. so the 
primary key for the last project is in the last_projects table. each user has only
one entry in this table.
Given all that, how do I map in hibernate the Project into the User entity?

Comment: Anything that you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

The association is a one-to-one association, so you need `@OneToOne`. It's materialized by a join table between both entities, so you need `@JoinTable`.

Read [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinTable.html) and the hibernate documentation for examples.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following and it worked like a charm:

```
<class ...>
    <attribute ...>

    ...

    <join table="LAST_PROJECTS" optional="true">
        <key column="USER_ID" />
        <many-to-one name="lastProject" column="PROJECT_ID"
            class="Project" not-null="true" unique="true"/>
    </join>

</class>
```

Thanks!